# JQuery getJson silently failing in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following request to flickR. Works great elsewhere but ID nothing happpens. According to my debugging proxy the call is not made. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

```
 get_photoset : function (id,extras, callback)
 {
 var base_url = this.get_service_base()+'=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&'+this.get_api_key()+'&photoset_id='+id+'&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';
 jQuery.getJSON(base_url,{'extras':extras}, function(data)
 {
  callback(data);
  });
 });
```

Comment: use ie's developer tools (F12) to see if there's any exception on the client side. also check whether you're in 'compatibility mode' or other some-such nonsense

Comment: thanks - found some errors. Now have something to go on.